is it possible to upgrade ColdFusion 11 to ColdFusion 2021?
I am new to ColdFusion. Due to the end of support for ColdFusion 11, we have been asked to upgrade to CF2021. We are currently running ColdFusion 11 on WebSphere Application Server 9.0.5. Is there any specific documentation I can follow to upgrade ColdFusion 11 to CF2021? Are there any database considerations or code modifications I need to make?
need suggestion from ColdFusion experts in the community.

Charlie Arehart has a great answer here: https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2022/09/upgrading-from-11-to-2021/; he's a great resource for anything CF-related in general.

Run through this entire lockdown guide to ensure your CF 2021 installation is as secure as possible before you migrate the existing application. https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2021/04/coldfusion-2021-lockdown-guide-available/

It is great that you are upgrading to a supported version. You should definitely do that. I will caution you that ColdFusion 2021 Core Support ends on 11/10/2025 and Extended Support a year later. You should think about going ahead to ColdFusion 2023 since you are going through this anyway.
